# What is the time complexity of subset testing?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, sets

Consider the following problem:

> Let $A = \{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $B = \{b_1,...,b_m\}$ be
>   two finite sets over $\mathbb{N}$. The sequences $a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_1,...,b_m$ do not have to be sorted.
>   Given as inputs the strings $a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_1,...,b_m$, determine if $A \subseteq B$.

What is the time complexity of this problem?

Comment: Would the question change if the sets were allowed to range over some arbitrary set?

Comment: You can do it in order $(n+m) \log \min(n,m)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus You sort one set and then do binary search?

Comment: Right, that's the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Since you talk about sets I assume that there are no duplicates.

You can  assume $n \le m$ otherwise you can answer "no" in time $O(1)$.
You can further assume $\max_{a \in A} a \le \max_{b \in B} b$, otherwise the answer is again "no", and can be found in time $O(\min\{m, U\})$, where $U = \max_{a \in A} a$.

Your problem can be solved in $O(\min\{m \log n, U\})$ worst-case time. To do so use the best of the following two strategies:

- Sort $A$. Keep a counter $x$ of how many elements from $B$ have been found in $A$. Initially $x=0$. For each element of $b \in B$ (in arbitrary order), determine whether $b \in A$ using a binary search. If $b \in A$ increment $x$. After all elements of $B$ have been examined, return true if and only if $x=n$.
- Keep an array $X[0, \dots, U]$ of $U+1$ boolean elements. Initially all the elements of $X$ are false. For each element $b \in B$, check if $b \le U$ and if that is the case set $X[b]$ to true. Iterate over the elements $a \in A$ and check whether $X[a]$ is true for all of them. If this is the case return true, otherwise return false.

Notice that $\Omega(m \log n)$ is a lower bound on the worst-case time complexity needed to solve your problem (as a function of $m$ and $n$) in the algebraic computation tree model. See Corollary 3 on page 147 (155 of the pdf file) [here](http://users.math.uoc.gr/~mkaravel/files/EuroCG06Proc.pdf).

You can also solve your problem in $O(m)$ expected time by using a hashset $H$:

- Insert all the elements of $B$ into $H$. This takes $O(1)$ expected time per insert operation, i.e., $O(m)$ time in total.
- For each element $a \in A$, check whether $a \in H$. This takes $O(1)$ expected time per check.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. But wouldn't it be faster to use a disjoint-set data structure? I thought one could first put $B$ in the disjoint set data structure and then search for every element of $A$ in $B$.

Comment: That would cost you $O(U)$ just to build the disjoint-set data structure. Plus, what's the advantage of using a disjoint-set data structure if you never perform any union operation?

Comment: While this is not a definitive answer, I do not expect to get a better one, so I've marked it as accepted.

Comment: I've changed my mind, considering that there are algorithms for sorting better than n log n, somebody might even know about a better algorithm right now.